# How can I calculate the vertex normals for my model(house)

Tags: c++, direct3d11

I just recently drew a house in my Direct3D11 application and it seems to look ok. But the only problem that I have is calculating the vertex normals for the house. Everytime the light strikes the house, it looks a little awkward, and the worst part is that the light wont even strike the inside of the house. (BTW I am using the spotlight technique to create light).

Down below is the vertex buffer that contains the vertices, texture coordinates, and the normals for my poorly drawn model. Can someone show me how to calculate the normals for the house?

```
void Create_Vertex_Buffer_for_House()
{
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC VertexBufferDesc;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA VertexBufferData;

ZeroMemory(&VertexBufferDesc, sizeof(VertexBufferDesc));
VertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
VertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex_Buffer) * 34;
VertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
VertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

/* Vertex coordinates, Texture Coordinates, and vertex normals (respectably)*/

Vertex_Buffer Vertices[] =
{
    /* Front wall of the house*/
    Vertex_Buffer(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 10.0f,    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f,    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,      10.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,     10.0f, 10.0f,    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),

    /* Front wall of the house*/
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 10.0f,    -4.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     -4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     10.0f, 0.0f,     -2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-2.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,    10.0f, 10.0f,     -2.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),

    /* Rooftop of house (front)*/
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 10.0f,       -4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 2.5f, -1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,        -4.0f, 2.5f, -1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f,  2.5f, -1.0f,   10.0f, 0.0f,        1.0f, 2.5f, -1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,    10.0f, 10.0f,       1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),

    /* Rooftop of the house(back)*/
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 2.5f, -1.0f,    0.0f, 10.0f,       -4.0f, 2.5f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,        -4.0f, 2.5f, -3.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f,  1.0f, -3.0f,   10.0f, 0.0f,         1.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f,  2.5f, -1.0f,   10.0f, 10.0f,        1.0f, 2.5f, -1.0f),

    /* Right wall of the house*/
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 10.0f,          1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f,           1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f,    10.0f, 0.0f,          1.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f, -1.0f, -3.0f,   10.0f, 10.0f,         1.0f, -1.0f, -3.0f),

    /* right wall of the house(small triangle strip)*/
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,     0.0f, 10.0f,          1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f, 2.5f, -1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f,           1.0f, 2.5f, -1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f,    10.0f, 0.0f,          1.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f),

    /* Left wall of the house*/
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, -1.0f, -3.0f,  0.0f, 10.0f,          -4.0f, -1.0f, -3.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,           -4.0f,  1.0f, -3.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   10.0f, 0.0f,          -4.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,   10.0f, 10.0f,         -4.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),

    /* Left wall of the house (triangle strip)*/
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 10.0f,            -4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 2.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,             -4.0f, 2.5f, -1.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f,  10.0f, 0.0f,             -4.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f),

    /* Back side of the house*/
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, -1.0f, -3.0f,  0.0f, 10.0f,            -4.0f, -1.0f, -3.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(-4.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,              -4.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f,  1.0f, -3.0f,   10.0f, 0.0f,              1.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f),
    Vertex_Buffer(1.0f,  -1.0f, -3.0f,  10.0f, 10.0f,            1.0f, -1.0f, -3.0f),
};


ZeroMemory(&VertexBufferData, sizeof(VertexBufferData));
VertexBufferData.pSysMem = Vertices;

device->CreateBuffer(&VertexBufferDesc, &VertexBufferData, &HouseVertexBuffer);


}
```

I am not sure if this will help, but down below is my method of implementing the spotlight technique in my pixel shader.

```
struct Light                                
{
float3 SpotLight_Position;
float range;
float3 SpotLight_Direction;             
float cone;
float3 attenuation;
float3 directional;
float4 ambient;                         
float4 diffuse;                         
};

cbuffer Constant_Buffer                 
{
float4x4 TRANSFORMEDMATRIX;             /* The final transformed matrix */
float4x4 WORLDSPACE;
Light LIGHT;                            
};


struct Vertex_Shader_Output                                 
{                                       
float4 Positions : SV_POSITION;         
float2 TextureCoord : TEXTURECOORD;     
float4 WorldSpace : POSITION;
float3 normal : NORMAL;                 
};

struct Sky_Vertex_Shader_Output         
{
float4 Positions : SV_POSITION;     
float3 TextureCoord : TEXTURECOORD;     
};
Texture2D Texture;                  /* Shader Resource for Pixel Shader*/
SamplerState Sampler;               /* Shader Resource for Pixel Shader*/


            /* PIXEL SHADER THAT WILL BE USED TO CREATE THE FLASH LIGHT*/
float4 Pixelshader(Vertex_Shader_Output input) : SV_TARGET  
{
float4 TextureFormat;
float3 lightToPixelVector;
float3 finalAmbient;
float HowMuchLight;
float distance;
float3 FinalColor = float3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        /* Sampling the texture and storing the format into an object*/
TextureFormat = Texture.Sample(Sampler, input.TextureCoord);

        /* Scaling the normal vector to a unit length*/
input.normal = normalize(input.normal);



        /* Creating a vector between the light source and the pixel positions of every object*/
lightToPixelVector = LIGHT.SpotLight_Position - input.WorldSpace;

        /* Getting the actual distance between the light source and the pixel position*/
distance = length(lightToPixelVector);

        /* Adding the ambient and the colors of the texture*/
finalAmbient = TextureFormat * LIGHT.ambient;

        /* If the pixel is too far from the light source*/
if (distance > LIGHT.range)
{
        /* Return the objects color without the light source*/
    return float4(finalAmbient, TextureFormat.a);
}



        /* Normalizing the vector to make sure its a unit length*/
lightToPixelVector = normalize(lightToPixelVector);

        /* Getting the angle between the light source and the vertex normal to see how much light that pixel will receive*/
HowMuchLight = dot(lightToPixelVector, input.normal);

if (HowMuchLight > 0.0f)
{
            /* Adding the diffuse and colors of the texture to make the final color*/
    FinalColor += TextureFormat * LIGHT.diffuse;
            /* Calculating the attenuation for the Final Color*/
    FinalColor /= (LIGHT.attenuation[0] + (LIGHT.attenuation[1] * distance)) + (LIGHT.attenuation[2] * (distance * distance));
            /* */
    FinalColor *= pow(max(dot(-lightToPixelVector, LIGHT.SpotLight_Direction), 0.0f), LIGHT.cone);
}

FinalColor = saturate(FinalColor + finalAmbient);

        /* Returning the final colors of the texture and the alpha value*/
return float4(FinalColor, TextureFormat.a);


}
```

Comment: Do you know the math behind surface normals? In Euclidian space the non-colinear points uniquely determine a plane. You can find the surface normal by taking the cross product of two vectors spanning the plane.

Comment: See [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh) and the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh/blob/master/DirectXMesh/DirectXMeshNormals.cpp) for ``ComputeNormals``